# Android fadein activity removes content too early

Tags: android

I'm trying to make transition effect when clicking on listview item to open new activity. 
The problem is when list item clicked - activity with list becomes white and content disappear instantly, then i see first part animation and then custom animation from newly created activity.
How can i make this content to disappear slowly?

```
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

((Activity) v.getContext()).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.list_fadein, R.anim.list_fadeout);
```

fadein:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
```

fadeout:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<alpha
    android:duration="0"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
```

I have another custom animation in new activity, so i dont care about second part (fadeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set,

> android:duration="0"

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:repeatCount="0" />
```

Here duration is the time to make it disappear.